# New instances of WebBrowser never load?

Tags: c#, internet-explorer, windows-phone-7, browser, windows-phone

Currently I have a WebBrowser object in my xaml page, if I call `browser.Navigate(uri)`, the page loads fine, but if I try to reset the WebBrowser by calling `browser = new WebBrowser();`, then the Navigate, nothing ever happens; the browser just stays blank white.

I've tried everything to get the browser to start after re-initializing it, but nothing seems to work. Is this a limitation of the platform or am I doing something incorrectly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your creating a new control, without ever hanging it into the visual tree of controls. May I ask why you create a new control in the first place? It seems like you just want to replace the old one with a new one. Wouldnt resetting the control be enough?

Comment: Currently I'm stuck at a problem that seems to _only_ be solved by actually restarting the application when the user wishes to perform a certain action (due to technical limitations). I wanted to try to see if simply creating a new instance of the browser would fix the problem, and thus not require an application restart.

Comment: My problem is basically the same as [this one](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-IE/Vsexpressvb/thread/171ea933-8e36-4e08-bb5b-1889262b0291) and coincidentally, the answer seems to be saying that this _will_ fix the problem, however, as I said, the browser doesn't work once I create the new instance.

Comment: OK, then the solution would be to remove the browser control from the visual tree, create a new one and add it back into the tree.

Comment: Well, that fixed the problem! Unfortunately, it didn't fix the technical issue that I was trying to fix by doing this. Oh well.  Thanks!